# Physics of tennis hit

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, everyday-life, collision, projectile

If one takes notice the tennis players hit the ball on the right corner that way: Their last step before the hit is on the right foot, then they hit and then their left foot goes up in the air about 20cm. This has something to do with the conservation of momentum. Can someone explain what happens from physical point of view? Why the left foot is going up?

Comment: Your question is framed in a confusing way. What do you mean by “They step on the right foot last”?

Comment: ok i rearange  the sentence

Comment: Can you provide a link with a video of what you are describing?  Or maybe some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of height. You can hit the ball faster and at a greater range of angles if you serve from a greater height. Angling your pelvis, so that one foot leaves the ground, raises the base of your spine and thus raises the shoulder joint, which in turn increases the height you can reach with your racquet.

Comment: This is no serve at all - you misunderstood - this is a regular hit  called forhand. No height in anyway. First they hit at the normal height and then the left foot goes up. Of course the serve is other thing. First jump and then hit.